# Flag '-l' in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS doesn't work

Tags: c++, linux, curl, cmake, shared-libraries

I have some code I wrote on my mac machine and it has been working perfectly but when I port it over to a Linux machine I get an `undefined reference to curl_easy_init`

My compiler flags include a `-lcurl` for linking.

Here's how I'm linking:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -L/curl/lib/dir -lcurl")
```

I've tried with and without the `-L/curl/lib/dir`

Curl is installed on this machine:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Comment: Hi! Is this /curl/lib/dir where your libcurl* libraries are located? Are you using system curl or compiled by yourself?

Comment: I don't think that is where they are located. Running `curl-config --libs` it returns `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl`. I though this would've been the actual flags but even with this, same error.

Comment: so -lcurl should be enough. What cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf says?

Comment: The command gives this. Also, the `-lcurl` was enough to work on my mac.

```# Multiarch support

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** add `-l` flags to *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS* and moreover to *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* (the flag `-l` is for the *linker*, not for a *compiler*).

For link with libraries use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html): it is specifically intended for that purpose:

```
target_link_libraries(<your-executable> curl)
```

---

When you add a flag to `*_FLAGS` variable, the flag is added **before the source file** (object file actually) in the linker's command-line. If the source file uses some function from the library, then the linker cannot find it.

As opposite, a flag produced by command `target_link_libraries` is added **after the source file** in the linker's command line.